# NamingException: Cannot create resource instance for jta.UserTransaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

I'm working with a Java program running on a Tomcat App server that is connected to a Teradata database that utilizes a `UserTransaction` & `session-factory` set in a hibernate configuration which connects to a datasource

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/My_DB</property>
        <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
        ....
```

And a method to get the Transaction Context

```
public UserTransaction getTransactionContext()
    throws Exception
    {
        if (this.ut == null) {
            ut = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        }
    return ut;
    }
```

However, `InitialContext` fails at `lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");` and returning:

```
03:27:37,530 ERROR [someServlet:555] Error in someMethod
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
```

I'm very new with using `jta.UserTransaction`; the datasource mapping works as it should however I can't seem to get the UserTransaction returned - the naming convention itself matches between the code and session factory. Could anyone provide some possibilities on why this is failing from a high (*or low*) level perspective? I can provide additional info if this is too vague a question.

Comment: Have you set the property for `transaction.factory_class` in your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: I've updated this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133663/namingexception-jta-usertransaction

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is a web server not a JTA compliant application server (e.g. JBoss, WebLogic, Glassfish).

If you want to use JTA you need to use a JTA stand-along implementation, like:

- [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home)
- [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/)
- [JBoss Transactions](http://narayana.jboss.org/resources/arjcore)

Embedding a standalone transaction manager will give you access to a JTA transaction manager exposing UserTransactions through JNDI.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad, this is a hibernate application and I don't belive it needs a standalone JTA impl. I've outlined more detail in the updated question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133663/namingexception-jta-usertransaction