# NamingException: jta.UserTransaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

I have a hibernate application which directly uses Java Transaction API resources. I'm trying to use UserTransaction to accomplish some basic database transactions

> The UserTransaction interface defines the methods that allow an
>   application to explicitly manage transaction boundaries

In hibernate.cfg.xml file I have the following properties:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/myDataSource</property>
    <property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
```

In the web.xml of the app, UserTransaction is set in the `<resource-env-ref>`

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>Object factory for MyBean instances.</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>UserTransaction</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

And in the code, I try to lookup the UserTransaction with `InitialContext` by its **JNDI** name

```
public UserTransaction getTransactionContext()
    throws Exception
    {
        if (this.ut == null) {
            ut = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        }
    return ut;
    }
```

However the following exception gets returned:

```
03:27:37,530 ERROR [someServlet:555] Error in someMethod
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
```

This application was ported over from a Weblogic server where it was functioning noramlly to Apache Tomcat; That being said - do I need to define **UserTransaction** in my `context.xml` in order for `getTransactionContext()` to locate it? If not, how can I appropriately return the UserTransaction within my code?

Comment: Hi @clay how did you solved this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting an application from a full-blown Java EE application server to Tomcat (web application server) requires some extra steps.

All Java EE servers come with a JTA transaction manager and their transaction engine manages transaction binding and transaction resolving, like the `UserTransaction` JNDI context.

You can use [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm) or [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/), and you need to set both the UserTransaction and the TransactionSyncronizationRegistry in Tomcat context.xml.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I suppose hibernate's integrated JTA alone was not enough for the AS. Do you know of a more standardized way to achieve this other than the article you've linked?

Comment: I personally used Bitronix which exposes the UserTransaction through JNDI. But there's no standard for stand-alone TM. The standard implies JEE.